# What is the optimal planetary sunshade arrangement?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, venus, terraforming, solar-sail

To cool a planet down, one may place a sunshade between the planet and the Sun.

On its own, this is not stable due to radiation pressure, so a simple scheme like a big circular piece of aluminium foil at L1 does not work.

Various schemes have been proposed, but I'm primarily interested in those that are in an equilibrium without support structures, that is, every part of the sunshade has radiation pressure and gravity in equilibrium.

In [Terraforming Venus Quickly](https://www.orionsarm.com/fm_store/TerraformingVenusQuickly.pdf), 1991, Paul Birch shows one arrangement:

[image: birchshade]

He states:

> The solution presented here is the best found to date. It is not necessarily the best possible solution

**Is that still true? Has there been any significant work on this since?**

Notes about the graphic above:

- The annular support mirror is not shown. It is essential to keep the sunshade hovering, and is detailed in his 1989 "Dynamic compression members"
- The "orbiting soletta" can be ignored, it's a light simulation system, so out of scope for this question.

Comment: A popular science take on terraforming Venus, though the shade illustrated is a very misunderstood and non-functional version of Birch's design: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G-WO-z-QuWI